# Cannot persist in HSQLDB using JPA 2.0, Spring 2.5.6, Hibernate 3.6.1 and Maven

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hsqldb

I'm trying to setup Spring using Hibernate and JPA, but when trying to persist an object, nothing seems to be added to the database.

I'm using the following:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
<!--         <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> -->
</bean>
```

My DataBase Properties:

```
database.password=
database.url=jdbc\:hsqldb\:file\:ClientHarness;shutdown\=true
database.username=sa
database.driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
```

`BroadcastMessageDao`:

```
@Repository("broadcastMessageDao")
public class BroadcastMessageDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<BroadcastMessage>
implements BroadcastMessageDao {

  public BroadcastMessageDaoImpl() {
    super(BroadcastMessage.class);
  }

  @Transactional
  public void persist(Object object){
    entityManager.persist(object);
  }
}
```

`GenericDaoImpl`:

```
public class GenericDaoImpl<T extends DomainObject>
implements GenericDao<T> {

  private Class<T> type;

  protected EntityManager entityManager = EMF.getInstance().createEntityManager();

  public GenericDaoImpl(Class<T> type) {
    super();
    this.type = type;
  }

  public void save(T object) {
    EntityTransaction trx = entityManager.getTransaction();
    trx.begin();
    try {
      entityManager.persist(object);
      entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
      trx.commit();
    } finally {
      if (trx.isActive()){
        trx.rollback();
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm running a `ClientHarness.main()`:

```
public class ClientHarness{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> contexts = new ArrayList<String>();

    contexts.add("classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");

    ApplicationContext appContext  = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
      contexts.toArray(new String[contexts.size()])
    );

    BroadcastMessageDao broadcastMessageDao = new BroadcastMessageDaoImpl();
    BroadcastMessage broadcastMessage = new BroadcastMessage();
    broadcastMessage.setId(1L);
    broadcastMessage.setMessage("***********************!!!");
    broadcastMessageDao.save(broadcastMessage);
    System.out.println("Id" + broadcastMessage.getId());
  }
}
```

Dependencies I'm using:

```
<!-- Hibernate Dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.6</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
  <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.0.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>cglib</groupId>
  <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
  <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.4</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>xerces</groupId>
      <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-js-resources</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
  <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
  <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
  <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

`persistence.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  version="1.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
>
  <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>sr.qualogy.hakrinbank.entities.BroadcastMessage</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I run `ClientHarness.main()`, I encounter an error:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a PropertyPlaceholder configured?

Comment: Yes. See code:
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
    <context:spring-configured/>

Comment: I made a mistake configuring Spring.

In the main class I changed the following code:
     BroadcastMessageDao broadcastMessageDao = (BroadcastMessageDao) appContext.getBean("broadcastMessageDao");

And in my applicationContext I changed the bean to:
    <bean   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> 
    </bean> 

 But now I get an error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection

Comment: You mean after uncommenting the datasource property line in your entityManagerFactory definition, you still have the same error?

Comment: Yes, After uncommenting the datasource property line I get the java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection

Comment: And by uncommenting you mean 'removing comment', so now you _have_ a datasource property injected into the EntityManagerFactory and you're still receiving the same error?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I mean. I also injected the Persistence Unit. Still the same Error :(

Comment: The error looks like this:
 Exception while saving broadcastMessage:     sr.anuskha.bank.entities.BroadcastMessage@16b904d
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must     supply a JDBC connection
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must     supply a JDBC connection
 at  org.hibernate.connection.UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.get    Connection(UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.java:54)
 at   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)

Answer (score 1):

I've just realized you have the followings:

```
BroadcastMessageDao broadcastMessageDao = new BroadcastMessageDaoImpl();
```

You should never do this while using spring, this way you won't get a spring-managed bean, thus none of its properties will be set. You should use `appContext.getBean(..)` instead. Not sure this will solve all your issues, but definitely this is wrong.

If after changes this you still have errors, please edit your question and add the latest versions of your files and also your latest full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: you're right. This was one of the problems. I have solved the user Must Supply a JDBC Conection. I will ask another Question, post the answer there, because I don't see an edit option. Thanks for ur help!